# How I send data to the database without refresh the page

Tags: javascript, jquery

How  I send data to the database without refresh the page
and send the data to the database without pressing the submit button

I saw many explanations, but all depends on  button ,, when pressing a button data is  sent to the database without refresh the page

I want is how to send the data to the database without pressing the submit button

I want  With pressure on the script data to be sent directly and without refresh the page

try this

```
<script>

$(function(){

  var A = {name:'khaled', password: 1234, submit: 'submit'};

    $.post('index.php',A,function(data){   

    return false;

    alert("OK");
});
});

</script>
```

But did not send the data to the database

**and try this**

```
<script>

$(function(){

  var A = {name:'khaled', password: 1234};

    $.post('index.php',A,function(data){

    $(data).find("input[name=submit]").click();

    return false;

    alert("OK");
});
});

</script>
```

**But updated Page**

(index.php)

```
<body>

user : <input type="text" name='name' />
password : <input type="text" name='password' />
<input type="submit" name='submit' value='موافق' />

</body>
```

**How do I send data to the database without pressing the submit button ??!!
and how I send data to the database without refresh the page  ??!!**

I do not want to press this button for data to be sent

```
<input type="submit" name='submit' value='موافق' />
```

**I want to send the data directly**

Comment: First of all, JavaScript by itself isn't going to send anything to the database.  It sends data to the web application, which internally handles that request and interfaces with the database.  So, when you say that your efforts didn't send anything to the database... What failed?  Was a request sent to the server-side application?  How did the server-side application respond to that request?  Once you have that working, choosing the client-side event to respond to (a button click or any other event) is the much easier step.

Comment: What do you mean by "without pressing submit"? Do you want to send the data each time the user hits a single key?

Comment: first block of code should have executed as long as path to url is valid. If you got no alert... what errors are thrown in console? Did you include jQUery library before your code?

Answer (score 2):

This is a little backwards, you have the right idea. But a little mixed up

```
<script>

$(function(){

  var A = {name:'khaled', password: 1234};

    $.post('index.php',A,function(data){

    $(data).find("input[name=submit]").click();

    return false;

    alert("OK");
});
});

</script>
```

If you want to do it without clicking the submit button.

You would want to likely `bind()`, `delegate()`, `on()`... `on()` being your best solution. A keypress or keyup event that when the enter key is pressed it submits the form. Triggering the submit button that way, or just doing a post that way, either way.

But in all:

```
<script>
  var A = {
            name: $('input[name="name"]).val(),
            password: $('input[name="password"]).val()
          };
    $.post('index.php',A,function(data){
        return false;
        alert("OK");
    });
</script>
```

is what you would need for the post following suit with your examples. However aside from keypress events of one form or another tied to the enter key, you could also base it on a timer that waits til the element is idle no key events in x time and pass the data, you could do it on `blur` of the element or any number of other things. Depends on the route you want to go overall

be mindful of your inputs though make sure they are what you want them to be on the backend, never trust javascript to send you exactly what you would expect. I would read up on basic database security and injection prevention techniques.

Comment: You should edit your really great answer to remove `.live()`....As of jQuery 1.7, the `.live()` method is deprecated. Use `.on()`  to attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use `.delegate()`  in preference to `.live()`. +1

Comment: valid point, and I should have emphasized on that as well. But removed live, and your comment says it all otherwise :)